# converting componentDidUpdate componentDidMount to hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, function, react-hooks

Learning react by coding, trying to convert this code into hooks version, but i'm not getting any error and still code is not working ( class version works), just want to have some advice or help if i have converted it in right way or not?

english is not my mother language so could be mistakes.

class:

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    this.updateCanvas();
    const img = this.refs.CameraImage;
    img.onload = this.updateCanvas.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    this.updateCanvas();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.snapshotInterval);
  }
```

converted version:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    updateCanvas();
    const img = CameraImage.current;
    img.onload = updateCanvas;

    return () => {
      img.onload = null;
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right according to [React docs about hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks):

```
// Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
});
```

And an example of converted `componentWillUnmount` to [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }
    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return function cleanup() {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
});
```

And code would like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //   componentDidMount run once when the component is mounted
    this.updateCanvas();
    const img = refs.CameraImage;
    img.onload = updateCanvas;      

    // will be called on component unmount 
    return () => {
        clearInterval(this.snapshotInterval);
    }
})
```

Comment: in Functional/hooks when using arrow function there is no need for 'this' keyword neither 'bind'

Comment: @walee thanks! It is just copy/paste type. Please, see my updated reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

**1 -**  you didn't pass an array into the `useEffect Hook`, so your component will continuously reload repeatedly.

**2 -** if you pass an empty array, then you are not watching any variables, and therefore it will only update the state on the first render, exactly like `componentDidMount`. in your case you are watching **snapshot** variable so add it as a dependency.
So just change your code like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    updateCanvas();
    const img = CameraImage.current;
    img.onload = updateCanvas;

    return () => {
      img.onload = null;
    };
  }, [snapshot]);
```

Comment: that img in dependency 'Cannot find name 'img'.ts(2304)
'

Comment: sorry ! my bad . I meant **snapshot** not **img** I edited my answer

Comment: I dont have a variable with that name, shoudnt that clearInterval be added to useeffect also ? I mean that componentWillUnmount

Comment: I don't know the other parts of your code. I' m  just assuming what variable you are using in your code .  just check your code and what variable your useEffect depends on and add it inside the arrays .  maybe it's ** CameraImage**